# Integrating a Fourier series

Tags: fourier-series

I am trying to integrate the Fourier series of $$f(x) = x,-\pi<x<\pi.$$ Using complex exponentials to find the series, I get the series $$\frac{2}{\pi} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n} \cdot \sin(nx).$$

Integrating will add an $n$ to the denominator and result in more rapid convergence. But when I try to integrate this series, I just end up with the series times the integral $\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\sin(nx) \,dx$, which makes everything zero. If I integrate it termwise, I also end up with zero.

Does anybody know what mistake I am making? I am told by that integrating this, one can obtain $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n^2} = 1 - \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{9}-\frac{1}{16} + ... = \frac{\pi^2}{12}.$$

*Any* help at all is appreciated, as I am quite flustered that this simple problem has stumped me.

Comment: If you integrate it termwise, what do you get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

]if you multiply by $x$ *before* integrating you have:
$$
\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} x^2 dx = 2 \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n} \cdot \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} x \sin(nx) dx
$$
which (integrated by parts) gives:
$$
\frac{2\pi^3}3 = 2 \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left[ (-1)^n \frac{x \cos nx}{n^2} \right]_{-\pi}^{\pi}
$$
or
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac1{n^2} = \frac{\pi^2}6
$$
from this you have (given absolute convergence of the series)
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{n+1}\frac1{n^2} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac1{n^2} -2 \cdot \frac14 \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac1{n^2} \\
= \frac{\pi^2}{12}
$$

Comment: Another great example of the ingenuity of Fourier series.

Comment: yes, indeed. we should occasionally be astonished at the beauty and profundity of these simple truths, necessary though they may be!

Comment: Thanks for this insightful answer. Could you please explain the second last line? How does one break up the $(-1)^{n+1}$ to get the original series minus $2 \cdot \frac{1}{4}$ times the series?

Comment: To avoid duplication of answers, see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1052058/writing-an-alternating-series-as-two-non-alternating-series

Answer (score 0):

Note that
$$\left( \sum_{i=0}^\infty a_i \right)^2 \ne\sum_{i=0}^\infty a_i^2$$
You need the cauchy product to evaluate the square by integrating "term-wise".